# Modify Windows Forms Topmost attribute

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I want some of my forms when opened stick to screen and disable the forms behind it, like the    MessageBox.Show(); messagebox,so that they alert the user with a beep if the user tries to click the forms behind the prioritized forms.
How I can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use showdialog instead of show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`

This will open a dialog up as a modal dialog (i.e cannot click others until this dialog and its children are closed)

e.g
`form1.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 0):

You should open your form using `ShowDialog()` method. This way you are opening your form as a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at the ake the `TopMost` property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx